# Talend Open Studio - How to create brand new project

Tags: talend

I need to create a brand new empty TALEND OPEN STUDIO project and then simply import some jobs from another already existing project.

Can someone help me on this please.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Talend Studio
2. You will be prompt with a small window which will have few options like

   **Select an existing Project**

   **Create a new Project**

and other options. You can click on **Create a new project** and then you can a give a name to that project.

Then your Talend window will be opened. On the left side of it you will have many options like **Business models, job designs, contexts** etc. Right click on Job designs and you will get the options of **import items** along with other options like **export items** etc. Click on it. You will get a window asking for your root directory of all the jobs. If you already have some archived files in a working environment then you can do that also, but I guess here it is not that case. For a normal job go with **select root directory option**. Select your directory where you have jobs. You can also import any particular job also. You have few buttons on right side saying **Select all, Deselect All** etc. These options are for parameter files and schema repositories etc. associated with your Job which you are importing. You can select or deselect according to your need. That's pretty much to import a simple Job.

There are many other options we will have to consider while importing jobs and creating new projects according to environment where we are working with Talend but for using Talend Open Studio for simple Jobs, all the above instructions would be fine.

**PS** - I am sorry I can't provide any graphics for it due to some reasons. But if you follow along with above instructions, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained information BUT simply needed to double check this:    When EXPORTING the jobs from what ever exisying project, can i export them to what ever folder i need to ? An then when in the other project (new one) i could then simply IMPORT them by following your instructions right ?