# Talend open studio - How to rename existing project

Tags: talend

I have this already existing Talend Open Studio project that I simply wish to rename from "testProject1" for example, to "Project1".

Can someone provide simple step by step please as for some forums talk about IMPORTING AN EXISTING PROJECT AND SIMPLY PROVIDE A NEW NAME and then CLICK ON THE BROWSE BUTTON BUT POINT to the already existing project name (testProject1).

Does anyone know if this will work ? Do we need to then copy/paste some folders here and there or no need ? Anyone knows another way to rename an already existing project name?

Comment: No one knows really ?

Comment: Yes that will work. I guess you would not have to do copy paste anything. Although while importing you can choose other parameter files etc. See following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209221/talend-open-studio-how-to-create-brand-new-project/47217177#47217177

Answer (score 4):

**FYI**. I haven't tested it on old **TOS** (Talend Open Studio). The current TOS version I'm using is **7.3**

Let's say we want to rename the current project name `OLD_PROJECT_NAME` to `NEW_PROJECT_NAME`

[image]

1. Close TOS
2. Go to your workspace and open your project root folder

[image]

3. Look for `.project file` and open it with your favorite text editor

   [image]
4. Change `OLD_PROJECT_NAME`, to the one you wanted and also **rename** the **root folder name** with the new name. For the sake of example, `NEW_PROJECT_NAME`

[image]

5. Open`talend.project` file and change`technicalLabel` attribute **value** to the new project name. Make the name all in **uppercase**. and change `label` attribute value to the project name you wanted in any letter case you want
   (if you don't get one, you can skip this step)
6. Open TOS and now you won't see the `OLD_PROJECT_NAME` on the list

[image]

7. Click on `Import an existing project`
8. On the new window, for `Project Name`, insert the new project name `NEW_PROJECT_NAME` and for `Select root directory` click browse and **go inside your root folder** and click `Select Folder`

If you encountered **java.lang.NullPointerException** while importing, move the newly renamed project folder to a desktop or other working area.

You can now start the import from there. This will copy the project to the Talend workspace after the import is done.

9. DONE

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that create a new project with whatever name you have and import all the jobs from the previous project. Previous project's folder will be in workspace folder or whatever path you have set for the workspace.

Alternate solution is given in the following link : 
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=41577

Google well before posting a question.